# How can I get all posts by a specific page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get all posts display on a specific page by a specific page id 
( I know that a page is a post with post_type = 'page')

The posts on page is setting by Post module

How can do that?

Comment: please could you explain brief.

Comment: do you want to display all posts or pages?

Comment: I have some page like Home page, and I want to get all post display on that page . ( I only want to get post ids)

Comment: are you creating page template to display this posts?

Comment: please add your code so i can help you

Comment: check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51068/display-all-posts-in-a-page-code-for-template

Answer (score 0):

`I want to get all posts display on a specific page by a specific page id.`

Try this.

```
?php
// get all posts
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'orderby'    => 'ID',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order'    => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1 
);
if (is_page('PAGE_ID_HERE')) : // replace page id here
$result = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : 
?>
<?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```